# How to disable Ctrl-Click in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I want to know if it's possible to remove the key bind on <kbd>Ctrl-Click</kbd> for the `goToDefinition` (<kbd>F12</kbd>) editor action.

This is so annoying, every time i try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> it trigger and go to the definition cause I'm holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while I'm highlighting the code with my mouse.

I have search for it on google but all y can change is the <kbd>F12</kbd> key bind for `goToDefinition` which is not what I want.

--- ***Update***

This is the feature I want to disable

[image]

I need to remove the <kbd>ctrl+click</kbd> key bind.
Even if I replace it, it doesn't work.

-- ***Update 2***

I finally found something on the subject [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/189)

But for me it doesn't work at all.

-- ***Update 3***

Created a new issue on GitHub ([#7827](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7827#issuecomment-229740455))
Look at it if you wanna see the update on the request.

Comment: For fellow searchers, the Github issue was closed as it was specific to this copy-paste bug. The overaching feature of disabling Ctrl-Click is at: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23957 and has not been fixed at time of writing.

Comment: Agreed. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23957 offers comments explaining best alternative temporary workaround for the time being (Selection -> Switch to Ctrl Click for Multi Cursor)

Comment: To be honest, until about 2 years'ish (give or take a couple months) I liked JetBrains WebStorm, IntelliJ, and CLion, as my Dev Env's of choice. Today, I use V.S. Code for almost everything, as it gives me control and access to a broad range of technologies & features without having to use multiple different IDE's. It has the most modern features of any IDE or Editor, Its the Jack knife of Dev Env, however, JetBrains still to this day, does somethings that VS Code hasn't implemented yet, one being Mouse click keybindings.

Comment: Does anyone know how to ctrl click into a vue component and have it actually take you to that file rather than just show definition?

Answer (score 7):

At the time of writing (2022) you can turn off this with workaround by setting following setting to 'ctrlCmd'.

[image]

How to open setting page in vs code?

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> and enter open setting (UI)
[image]

- Note that if you are also looking for Ctrl+Click for word selection, it is still not possible. [See my another answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72304645/4188314)
- And yea, the [dreaded (and famous) issue #3310](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3130) is never really happened, even after 6 years.

Comment: more details on this solution can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics

Comment: After an update rendered the default "go to definition" key binding not working, changing this setting to `alt` did the trick. Thank!

Answer (score 3):

There is a VS Code feature request for this on GitHub, under the more general heading [Allow customization of mouse shortcuts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3130).

Anyone interested in this VS Code feature should comment/vote there. (The Ctrl-click-specific GitHub posts have been closed off and linked to this one. Ex. [#16974](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16974))

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way:

1. Press F1 (opens search bar).
2. Search `multi-cursor modifier`
3. Just press the toggle appearing as the search result.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Add the following lines in ***keybingings.json*** to disable (actually override default behaviour) mouse+ click

```
[
    { "key": "ctrl+[mouse button]",   "command": "cursorWordLeft",
                                         "when": "editorTextFocus" }
]
```

To open key bindings file, traverse

> File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

Comment: maybe i do it wrong..

Should i change [mouse button] by left or right ??
cause when i write the exact same thing as you it doesnt work :/

Comment: Already tried and it doesn't work like i said. When i ctrl+mouseUp/Down it go to def... I have updated my original post with more details @PandiyanCool

Comment: ATM VS Code has no support to configure the mouse behaviour. This answer is not correct

Comment: This answer used to work for me but no longer works. VSCode must have removed this feature =/

Comment: Someone downvoting this answer after 4 years. :) VSCode itself might have dropped that feature. :)