# How can I disable ctrl+click on non-link words in VS Code's terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like the ctrl + click feature in the editor but having it in the terminal is a real pain.

I'm referring to the search feature when I click at any word that isn't a URL, file link, or folder link.

[image]

This question is specifically about word links in the terminal. It is therefore not a duplicate of [How to disable Ctrl-Click in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683703).

Comment: Yeah I can see it being useful if I don't have the habit of keep pressing the ctrl key when I copy -> paste within the same terminal. But with that habit this is more pain than useful.

Comment: No, I want to disable the search in terminal, nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preface, you're not alone in finding this behaviour undesirable. It's been brought up as a pain point before (Ex. [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99924#issuecomment-648832402)).

This is the "terminal word links" feature that was added in the May 2020 release of VS Code (1.46). See [the related release notes section](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_improved-link-support). I don't think there's any way to turn it off (?)

Actually, I seem to be getting some success by putting the following in settings.json:

```json
"terminal.integrated.wordSeparators": " ()[]{}',\"`─‘’|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
```

FYI, general docs about terminal links in VS Code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9477338/natthaphon-hongcharoen).

---

The last time it was asked about whether a dedicated feature could be added to disable the search box that appears when clicking something that doesn't resolve to anything unambiguously, the request was declined. You might not like what I'm about to quote from the maintainers, but I'm going to say that I see it with favourable light, and I agree with their take and find it to be quite reasonable, so please find it in your heart to accept it.

See issue ticket [Turn off the cmd+click feature in terminal
#136202](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136202). Quoting Daniel Imms from [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136202#issuecomment-956525805) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136202#issuecomment-957690117) comment of theirs there:

> You can disable the link hover with `"terminal.integrated.showLinkHover": false`, we don't plan on allowing disabling of cmd+click to activate links, just don't press cmd if you don't want to use it? Cmd+click doesn't conflict with any other feature.
>
> I guess just be a little more careful or slow down when you click. This would be like requesting to disable symbol navigation in the editor which would end up getting used by maybe a handful of people but everyone ends up seeing a new setting in the settings editor, it also takes effort to maintain settings and it's not worth it because of that.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that issue ticket simply by googling "`vscode disable terminal links`".

Comment: Which is an equivalent of "Don't use VSCode in laptop unless you have a mouse and enough space to use it". A shame that every single "maintenance" make it worse and those problems were kept that way for the sake of more "maintenance".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the commits around early to mid 2020, that "feature" was added probably by the guy who answer [this question](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136202) that @starball provide above.

So it is "solved" by just use any version before that.

In fact, 1.45.0 has a terminal that works perfectly with URLs minus this nonsense.
[image: url]

If it really was the guy who say "we don't plan on allowing disabling of cmd+click to activate links" that added that feature this is a really dumb problem to have.